# Rest Json application works on localhost but when I upload to server ,It gives 404 error

Tags: java, json, web-services, maven, http-status-code-404

My Spring Rest Json application works on localhost but when I upload to server ,It gives 404 error. I attached my pagecode,web.xml,pom.xml and 3 screenshots from my testing urls.

java class;

```
@RestController
public class TaskController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public @ResponseBody WorksheetMobile test(@RequestBody UrlParameters param) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        WorksheetMobile item = new WorksheetMobile();
        item.setWorksheetId("");
        item.setTaskId("asd-asd-asd-asd-asd");
        item.setWorkDate(cal);
        item.setTimeSpent(100);
        item.setTimeSpentBeInvoiced(70);
        item.setDefinition("definition");
        item.setIsIPMSWorksheet(true);
        item.setUrlParameters(param);
         return item;
    }

}
```

here is my web.xml;

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>WebService</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WebService</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0-rc3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and here is my screenshots while trying to connect localhost and server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxM3f.png)

As you can see It runs in localhost but when I tried same url in server it gives error(I also tried Jersey Web Application url);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t4g2.png)

Comment: Which application-server are you using? if it's Tomcat, then did you upload the file as ROOT.war in webapps folder, then only your context-path is set to `/` .

Comment: I'm using tomcat. I deployed project as WebService.war. (Path is /WebService)

Comment: Take a look at the logs (TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out) - the webapp might have not been deployed.

Comment: I looked "C:\tomcat\logs\catalina.2016-02-26". When I try to connect "http://demo.deris.com.tr:9090/WebService/test" I doesn't write anything to log. But when I try to connect "http://demo.deris.com.tr:9090/WebService/api/test" It writes this;""

Comment: 26-Feb-2016 15:48:17.945 INFO [http-apr-9090-exec-34] com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes

Comment: 26-Feb-2016 15:48:18.584 INFO [http-apr-9090-exec-34] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.14 09/09/2012 07:21 PM'

Comment: 26-Feb-2016 15:48:18.709 SEVERE [http-apr-9090-exec-34] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init> The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

Comment: I also see this log in "localhost.2016-02-26" under tomcat logs folder.

Comment: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web application [/WebService] threw load() exception
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/ader/controller/TaskController : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.ader.controller.TaskController)

Comment: please add below and check with proper class and package names

<init-param>
   <param-name>class name</param-name>
            <param-value>Resource classes full package name</param-value>
</init-param>